# Read structured binary file

Tags: java, file, datainputstream

I want to read a binary file in Java. I know that the file contains a succession of data structures as: ANSI ASCII byte string, Integer, ANSI ASCII byte string. How can I read and get the data of the file, even if we suppose that the number of data structures is already known (N)? I see that the interface [DataInput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) has a method readUTF() to read a String, but it uses UTF-8 format. How can we hanle the case od ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible (and efficient) approach, I think, is:

1. Open a `FileInputStream`.
2. Obtain a `FileChannel` using the stream's `getChannel()` method.
3. Map the channel to a `MappedByteBuffer` using the channel's `map()` method.
4. Access the data through the buffer's various `get*` methods.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int n = 10;
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("bin");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String s1 = readAscii(is);
        int i1 = readInt(is);
        String s2 = readAscii(is);
    }
}

static String readAscii(InputStream is) throws IOException, EOFException,
        UnsupportedEncodingException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (int b; (b = is.read()) != 0;) {
        if (b == -1) {
            throw new EOFException();
        }
        out.write(b);
    }
    return new String(out.toByteArray(), "ASCII");
}

static int readInt(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[4];
    int n = is.read(buf);
    if (n < 4) {
        throw new EOFException();
    }
    ByteBuffer bbf = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf);
    bbf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    return bbf.getInt();
}
```

Comment: Mere code isn't an answer. You have to explain it, and explain how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we handle the case of ASCII?

You can handle it with readFully().

NB readUTF() is for a specific format created by DataOutput.writeUTF(), and by nothing else that I aware of.